# New GWT Maven plugin how pass parameters to compiler?

Tags: javascript, java, maven, gwt, maven-plugin

glad to ask you.

I am trying to migrate my old GWT eclipse project to the new GWT Maven Pulgin (not Mojos's).
I want to know how this new pluging maganes the GWT compiler parameters like draftCompile and localWorkers, I have it not  clear. Thank you in advice.

I tried the goal mvn gwt:compile -DdraftCompile=true, but I want to add this flag in the POM XML file.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your pom.xml, you add a `<configuration>` node.  For example:

```
    <plugin>
      <groupId>net.ltgt.gwt.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <extensions>true</extensions>
      <configuration>
        <sourceLevel>${maven.compiler.release}</sourceLevel>
        <moduleName>${gwtModule}</moduleName>
        <failOnError>true</failOnError>
        <logLevel>${gwt.logLevel}</logLevel>
        <style>${gwt.style}</style>
        <draftCompile>${gwt.draftCompile}</draftCompile>
        <localWorkers>${gwt.localWorkers}</localWorkers>
        <startupUrls>${gwtRunTargetUrl}</startupUrls>
        <codeserverArgs>
          <arg>-bindAddress</arg> <arg>0.0.0.0</arg>
        </codeserverArgs>
        <devmodeArgs>
          <devmodeArg> -bindAddress 0.0.0.0 </devmodeArg>
        </devmodeArgs>
        <jvmArgs>
          <jvmArg> -Xss4M </jvmArg>
          <jvmArg> -Dorg.eclipse.jetty.LEVEL=INFO </jvmArg>
          <jvmArg> -Dorg.eclipse.jetty.util.log.class=org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog 
        </jvmArgs>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

In my example, some configuration values have been defined earlier in the properties section of the pom.xml.  E.g.

```
<properties>
  <gwtRunTargetUrl>app.html</gwtRunTargetUrl>
  <gwtModuleName>foo.WebFormApp</gwtModuleName>
  <gwtModuleShortName>WebFormApp</gwtModuleShortName>
  <gwt.localWorkers>2</gwt.localWorkers>
  <gwt.draftCompile>false</gwt.draftCompile>
  <gwt.style>OBFUSCATED</gwt.style>  <!-- OBFUSCATED/PRETTY/DETAILED -->
  <gwt.logLevel>INFO</gwt.logLevel>
</properties>
```